# Testing methods in @Component class having @PostConstruct anotation

Tags: spring, testing, annotations

I am testing service methods that are placed in controllers in spring applications. It seems to me that my problem is that one essential service method call is done in class which is anotated `@Component` and the method call is inside  `@PostConstruct` anotated method.

```
@Component
public final class Helper

@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
  stuff = service.getNessesaryStuff();
}
```

The contents of the stuff are coming from a database and they vary in each test. That's why database is populated with needed data before each test. Without the data the other service methods are not working. I have checked that the right data goes to database exactly like intended, but it does not affect right away. I need to run same test couple of times before it gets the right data and passes.

Any fix?

When running the application, Helper class is created itself. When running tests, I need to make a bean of it to avoid `NullPointerExceptions`.

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is. You mentioned `@PreConstruct` but the piece of code shows `@PostConstruct`. Maybe you need to post more from your actual testing code and explain a bit better what you need and what is not working.

Comment: PostConstruct is right. My thoughs got messed up.

Comment: It is, still, not clear what you want. :)

Comment: How do you access Helper?